# What is the probability that in a class of $25$ students at least three are born in the same month?

Tags: probability

> What is the probability that in a class of $25$ students:
>
> - at least two are born in the same month;
> - at least three are born in the same month?

It's obvious that the first probability $P(A)$ is $1$ because there are $12$ months in a year, so there must be two students that are born in the same month. I am not sure that my teacher is ever going to be okay with this solution. I am expected to solve the problem using $Pr(A)=\dfrac{m}{n}$, where $m$ is the number of favorable outcomes, and $n$ is the number of all outcomes. What are the values of $m$ and $n$ in this case? It must be $m=n=12$, but I am not sure I get it. Can someone explain to me why is this?

Comment: The correct phrase to use to make sure your teacher is okay with the first one is "by the Pigeon hole principle"

Comment: You should google The Pigeon Hole principal".  It was derived precisely for these types of situations.  ... We can set up the first as the number of ways for $25$ students to have been born in different months as $12*11*10*.......*(12-25) =12*11*10*....*2*1*0*(-1)*...*(-13) = 0$.  And we could set up a complicated way of figuring out how many way to have $k$ choices among $m$ student with with at most $j$ per choice (example what if there were only $18$ students born among $12$ months and at most $2$ per month).  That could be done and it'd have a $0$ as a factor.  But why bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your teacher will accept that.  $n = 12^{25}$ is then number of ways in which $25$ kids can be born in one of $12$ months.

$k= 0$ which is the number of ways there are at most $2$ that are born on the same month. And $m = 12^{25}-k = 12^{25}$ are then ways in which at least $3$ are born on the same month.

The question is: how do we calculate that $k=0$.  Cite "the pigeon hole principal":

If at most $2$ are born each of the the twelve months then at most $2*12$ are born in twelve of the twelve months.  This accounts for at most $24$ kids.  There is at least one more kid but no more months available.

SO this can not be done.

That is an acceptable mathematical argument.

So $P($at least 3$) = 1- P($ at most 2$) = 1-\frac {0}{12^{25}} = 1-0 = 1$.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your thoughts about the pigeon hole principle. I get that $n=12^{35}$.

Comment: If it isn't the case that three kids share a birth month, then at most two share a birth moth.  So in any of the twelve months only two kids (at most) can have a birthday in that month.  So for all of the $12$ months only $2*12$ kids can have birthdays in them.  But there are $25$ kids.  So either this is a contradiction or one of the kids was never born.